# Iterate through column A and do until empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script

My script is working but it times out. I am unsure as to what I can do to keep it from doing this.

```
function archived(e) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('IVA');
 const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Archived Videos');
 const numColumnsToMove = 20;
 var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('IVA');
  var myValues = sheetTo.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
    if (myValues[i][0] === '')
      return i + 1;
 const rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumnsToMove);
 const values = rangeToMove.getValues();
 appendRowsV(targetSheet, values, 1);
 sheet.deleteRows(e.range.rowStart, 1);
 var lRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sheet.getLastColumn(), range = sheet.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
}
```

As an FYI my sheet has 1500 rows and 15 columns. don't know if that is important or not.

Comment: What kind of trigger are you using? Or, what is the structure of e?

Comment: I was using an on edit simple trigger. but I'll be using a timed trigger

Comment: The event objects are totally different.  Also appendRowsV is undefined. I recommend that you go back and look at the event objects for a timebased trigger and rewrite you code.  Also keep in mind that any returns are pointless because you returning it to a trigger which wont do anything.  You might wish to try another question when you return.

Comment: appendRowsV is defined elsewhere. but I will look at the events objects.

Comment: That fine for you but we require a [mcve]

Comment: I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case. As far as I can tell from your code you're trying to append all data from the sheet 'IVA' at the bottom of the sheet 'Archived Videos'. It can be done this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var src_range = ss.getSheetByName('IVA').getDataRange();
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Archived Videos');
  var last_row = dest_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange('A' + last_row);
  src_range.copyTo(dest_range);
}
```

Comment: I also need to set value of src range to null

Comment: Add the line: `src_range.clearContent()` or `src_range.clear({contentsOnly: true})` at the end.